# Spring boot request aspect bean with @scheduled task

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, aop

I use in a spring boot application a component as a Spring aspect:

```
@RequestScope
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyComponentAspect{
     @Around("execution(public * com.mycompany..MyService.saveEntity(*))")
     public void getsaveEntityExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
       ...
     }
     // other advices
}
```

I need to collect execution time of some methods for each http request the app receives. So as you can see, I have annotated the aspect with @RequestScope.

I Recently add a scheduled task which also needs to call the MyService.saveEntity method.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class MyScheduledJob {

    private MyService myService;
    // ...
    
}
```

Of course this is not working because the scheduledJob can't actually find the request scope bean and fails. Actually I don't want the aspect to be enabled when the scheduledJob is running.

Is there a way to let the aspect enabled for normal web request and not for disable it for scheduled task?

Comment: Why would it need to be request scoped for that? There is no state so everything is inside the method, no need to make it requestscoped.

Comment: I want to mesure exécution time for concurrent calls. Without using scope request on my aspect I don't see a easy way to do those mesurement. If my aspect is a singleton, concurrent calls will produce the  same mesure.

Comment: No it won't. Your aspect doesn't have state so nothing is shared between threads. If you have a start time inside the method and end time. It will just record the start/end for each method call. So no need to make it request scoped.

Comment: That is my question. Making it request scope doesn't work because of the @Scheduled task. How can I figure this out?

Comment: Read... Plpease read you don't need the request scope... It doesn't add anything. Which is what I said twice before already... Remove the `@RequestScope`.